# Unity animator causing lights to turn on sluggishly?

Tags: unity, animation, animator

I've got lights on a vehicle that I am controlling using several animations. I have an animator with multiple layers and everything works properly. However, I am having an issue where the lights take roughly half a second to reach full brightness. In the inspector, it does not show the intensity rising from 0-3, it just shows them already set to 3. If I preview the animation without the controller, the lights are on instantly. But for whatever reason, when running through the controller, they "come on slowly", not like when you flip a switch and lights are instantly "on", these turn on and take time to reach full brightness. I have ensured I do not have an exit time, and do not have fixed duration checked, and transition duration is set to 0. I have also tried to speed up the animation "Speed" property just to see if it would change anything but had no effect. Does any one have any idea why this is happening? thank you!

[image][image]

Comment: Can you show us how you've configured your animation layers that affect these lights?

Comment: @DMGregory added pictures